# Properties with same name are getting over written in spring vault 3.0.0

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-properties, spring-cloud-vault-config

I have configs in HashiCorp vault with same names in different path.But when i try to access it, i am always end up with the config1 prop1 value is getting overridden by config2 prop1

**Vault Path**

---

```
path/stage/config1
    prop1
path/stage/config2
    prop1
```

**Spring vault version** :spring-cloud-starter-config-3.1.1
**Spring boot starter version** : 2.7.1

### **properties.yaml**

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-app
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      enabled: false
  cloud.vault:
    uri: https://vaulturi
    connection-timeout: 5000
    read-timeout: 15000
    authentication: token
    token: ${keeper.token}
    namespace: name1/name2
    fail-fast: true
    kv:
      enabled: true
      backend: path/stage
      default-context: config1
  config:
    import: vault://path/stage/config1,vault://path/stage/config2
app:
 prop1:{$(prop1)}
```

Can i access prop1:{$(prop1)} like prop1:{$(config1.prop1)}

When i check the value in actuator/env, i get the following response

```
    {
        "name": "path/stage/config1",
        "properties": {
            "prop1": {
                "value": "test1"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "path/stage/config2",
        "properties": {
            "prop1": {
                "value": "test2"
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Can some one help me to fix this

Thanks
Arun

Answer (score 0):

Try to import vault://path/stage and then you have config1.prop1 and config2.prop1
You can then map them to specific properties.